# Launching Scrapyd with multiple configurations

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to develop my Scrapy application using multiple configurations depending on my environment (e.g. development, production). My problem is that there are some settings that I'm not sure how to set them. For example, if I have to setup my database, in development should be `"localhost"` and in production has to be another one.

How can I specify these settings when I'm doing `scrapy deploy` ? Can I set them with a variable in command-line?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the deploy options in your scrapy.cfg file. For example:

```
[deploy:dev]
url = http://dev_url/

[deploy:production]
url = http://production_url/
```

With that, you could do:

```
scrapyd-deploy def
```

or

```
scrapyd-deploy production
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the answer in the following link :

https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2018/10/09/using-local-settings-in-a-scrapy-project/

I copy here for quick reference:

Edit the **settings.py** file so it would read from additional settings files depending on a SCRAPY_ENV environment variable

Move all the settings files to a separate config directory (and change scrapy.cfg so it knew where to look

The magic happens at the end of settings.py：

```
from importlib import import_module
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
import logging
import os

SCRAPY_ENV=os.environ.get('SCRAPY_ENV',None)
if SCRAPY_ENV == None:
    raise ValueError("Must set SCRAPY_ENV environment var")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})

# Load if file exists; incorporate any names started with an
# uppercase letter into globals()
def load_extra_settings(fname):
    if not os.path.isfile("config/%s.py" % fname):
        logger.warning("Couldn't find %s, skipping" % fname)
        return
    mdl=import_module("config.%s" % fname)
    names = [x for x in mdl.__dict__ if x[0].isupper()]
    globals().update({k: getattr(mdl,k) for k in names})

load_extra_settings("secrets")
load_extra_settings("secrets_%s" % SCRAPY_ENV)
load_extra_settings("settings_%s" % SCRAPY_ENV)
```

Then in the python file you want to get the variables defined in the setting, use the following code

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()
env_variable = settings.get('ENV_VARIABLE')
```